Why does a 'deducing this' template give different results than overloading by rvalue/lvalue?
I wrote this simple test to overload based on whether this is an rvalue or an lvalue. The original version had additional cases, but I reduced it down to the one that's puzzling me.
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int pp=0;  
  A(int p) : pp(p) {}
  A &prop(int nn) & {pp=nn; return *this;}
  A &&prop(int nn) && {pp=nn; return std::move(*this);}
};

struct B {
  B(const A &aa) {std::cout << "COPY: " << aa.pp << std::endl;}
  B(A &&aa) {std::cout << "MOVE: " << aa.pp << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
  A aa(99);
  B b4(aa.prop(33).prop(4));    // 4 COPY
  std::cout << "4 == " << aa.pp << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

The output is what I expected
COPY: 4
4 == 4

So far, so good. Then I modified A to use a method that deduces this:
struct A {
  int pp=0;  
  A(int p) : pp(p) {}

  template <typename self> A prop(this self &&me, int nn) {
    me.pp=nn;
    return me;
  }
};

I expected to get the same result, but I don't:
MOVE: 4
4 == 33


Why does the second version call the move method?

Even though it calls the move method, I would still expect to see nn set to 4 and not 33.


What's going on?

In the "deduced this" case, you always return an A object by value, so:
aa.prop(33).prop(4)

assigns 33 to aa.pp, and then the prop(4) part assigns 4 to pp of the copy of aa you just returned, thus leaving aa.pp as 33.
What you need to do is return an A& or A&& reference, depending on how this gets deduced.  To do this, you can use decltype(auto) to deduce the value category of the returned object and return the correct type.

decltype(auto) would always return self&. Using self&& and std::forward<self>(me) would return the original type.

@Jarod42 : Not in C++23, which incorporated P2266
